# How to implement sign in with google in Angular

Tags: angular, google-api, openid-connect, google-signin, angular-social-login

I am trying to implement google sign-in functionality in my angular app. I have used two packages here `@abacritt/angularx-social-login` and `angular-oauth2-oidc`.

I have created a custom provider called `google-authentication.service.ts` same as from this repository [Link](https://github.com/Jin-K/azama-box/blob/main/projects/jin-k/google-oidc-login-provider/src/lib/google-oidc-login-provider.service.ts). With this approach after a successful sign-in the dialog is not closed and also I am not able to get the logged-in user details.

Question: Please suggest a way to close the dialog after a successful sign-in and get the logged-in user credentials

google-authentication.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthenticationService implements LoginProvider {
    constructor(private readonly _oAuthService: OAuthService) {
        this.createConfiguration();
    }

    private readonly _tokenReceived$ = this._oAuthService.events.pipe(
        filter((e) => e.type === 'token_received'),
        map(() => true as const)
    );

    private createConfiguration(): void {
        let redirectUri = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
        if (redirectUri.endsWith('/')) {
            redirectUri = redirectUri.substring(0, redirectUri.length - 1);
        }

        this._oAuthService.configure({
            issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
            strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
            redirectUri,
            silentRefreshRedirectUri: redirectUri,
            useSilentRefresh: true,
            clientId: environment.googleClientId,
            scope: 'openid profile email'
        });
    }

    async initialize(autoLogin?: boolean): Promise<void> {
        await this._oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocument();
        if (autoLogin) {
            await this._oAuthService.tryLoginImplicitFlow();
        }
    }

    async signIn(): Promise<SocialUser> {
        const tokenReceivedPromise = firstValueFrom(this._tokenReceived$);

        await this._oAuthService.initImplicitFlowInPopup();
        await tokenReceivedPromise;

        return this.createUser(this._oAuthService.getIdToken());
    }

    async getLoginStatus(): Promise<SocialUser> {
        if (this._oAuthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
            return this.createUser(this._oAuthService.getIdToken());
        } else {
            throw `No user is currently logged in`;
        }
    }

    async signOut(revoke?: boolean): Promise<void> {
        if (revoke) {
            this._oAuthService.revokeTokenAndLogout(true, true);
        } else {
            this._oAuthService.logOut(true);
        }
    }

    private createUser(idToken: string): SocialUser {
        const user = new SocialUser();
        const payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(idToken.split('.')[1]));
        user.idToken = idToken;
        user.id = payload.sub;
        user.name = payload.name;
        user.email = payload.email;
        user.photoUrl = payload.picture;
        user.firstName = payload['given_name'];
        user.lastName = payload['family_name'];
        return user;
    }
}
```

Login-component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._googleAuthService.initialize();
}

signUpWithGoogle(event: Event): void {
    this._googleAuthService
        .signIn()
        .then((user) => {
            //not showing anything in console
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Why did you need a custom provider? It says `Supports authentication with Google, Facebook, Amazon, Microsoft, and VK out of the box`.

Comment: because with googles default button builder there are only few styles i can apply. My design does not match with those pre defined presets

Comment: default button means gis client, which has very limited number of styles we can apply

Answer (score 17):

It's work for me in this way.
According to the new documentation of Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview), you should follow next steps:

1. Create a google app in google cloud console platform and generate a client id.
2. Load the client library. Add this script "`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`" async defer>" between the `<head></head>` tags of your index.html file of Angular project.
3. Add this code on ngOnInit() function in the component that you would like to have "Sign in with Google button."

> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.initialize({
>     client_id: "YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT ID",
>     callback: this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this),
>     auto_select: false,
>     cancel_on_tap_outside: true,
>
>   });
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.renderButton(
>   // @ts-ignore
>   document.getElementById("google-button"),
>     { theme: "outline", size: "large", width: "100%" }
>   );
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: PromptMomentNotification) => {});
> }
> ```

> ```
> async handleCredentialResponse(response: any) {
>   // Here will be your response from Google.
>   console.log(response);
> }
> ```

4. Add div or button element to the html file of this component, with the same id that you mentioned into the initialization. ( "google-button" ):

> `<div class="" id="google-button"></div>.`

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: For anyone that uses this solution, it seems that `handleCredentialResponse` is called from _outside Angular_. If you want to do something _inside Angular_ , per example changing one of the component variables, you need to use NgZone. Just import NgZone in the constructor, and in `handleCredentialResponse` call whatever you need to run _inside Angular_ from `this.ngZone.run()`.

Per example, to change a localVariable in the component, `this.ngZone.run(() => this.localVariable = "newValue")`

Comment: This works first time, but when I logout and return to the login page, button is not rendered anymore.